# How send html form to email, viber, telegram without php?

Tags: javascript

Are there any free projects for this? Is it possible to solve this problem without examining the server part?

Comment: firebase cloud functions might help you. You may need the bare minimum of a node server but I think it allows you to have backend code without a backend.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For telegram i use https://formfor.site/ I hope this can help you.